# Solving this limit without L'Hopital

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to find the solution for the following limit without using L'Hopitals rule.

The indeterminate form of $\frac{0}{0}$ is obtained but both the conjugate and or squeeze theorem can't be applied here (I think). I know that the solution is supposed to be 3 but I can't see how to reach it.

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{sin3x}{x}$

Comment: $\frac{\sin 3x}x=3\cdot\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}$, and you should know $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 3x}{3x}$.

Comment: Do you know equivalent functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin3x}{x}=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} 3\frac{\sin3x}{3x}$$

Comment: Does this rule have a name? I don't understand why this is allowed.

Comment: $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin ax}{ax}=1$